# Group by products by attribute in minicart - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, collection, best-practice

I want to know how to **group by** the products of a minicart by `vendor_id` attribute, evidently each product has this attribute `vendor_id`. Then I display at the header of each group the name of the vendor, i tried something but i need some **group by**. I have also some load in a foreach :/

`checkout/cart/minicart.phtml`:

```
 ...
<div class="inner-wrapper">
    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
         <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
             <ol class="mini-products-list">
                 <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                     <?php $vendor = Mage::getModel('udropship/vendor')->load( $_item->getUdropshipVendor(), 'vendor_id'); ?> //here i get a vendor id
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-12 vendor-info">
                             <table class="table table-bordered">
                                 <thead>
                                     <tr>
                                         <th class="col-md-6 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $this->__('Vendeur : ') ?></th>
                                         <th class="col-md-6 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $this->__('Montant minimum de commande : ') ?></th>
                                     </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td class="text-center"><b><?php echo $vendor->getVendorName() ?></b></td> //here i get a vendor name
                                         <td class="text-center"><b><?php echo $vendor->getMinimumOrderAmount().'&nbsp;'.'€' ?></b></td> //here i get another attribute
                                     </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?> //here we display all products
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
             </ol>
</div>
...
```

The result:

[image]

What i want:

[image]